# Custom css of one application is reflected in every application inside the launchpad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sapui5

**Hi all,**
      I have used standard sapui5 classes and overriding them using **!important** to those properties. The issue is when my app is opened and closed , the other application in the launchpad also inherits the css that is marked with !important property.

**Things I have tried**

- Added a class to the container view and cascading the style from the class but this works partially
- Added a class to the control and styling the control. Even this is not working in all cases.

So looking forward for your answers in different perspective with the use of css, javascript or jQuery.

Comment: How can we give you a magic solution? We don't even have a single line of code. It's like calling your mechanic on the phone and say "My car doesn't work", and expecting a fix.

Comment: I dont think there is a need for code in the situation , Sorry if I am wrong. Just i need a method of removing those css reflected in other applications.

Comment: You mean..Any chrome extension is added.Their CSS is overriding yours

Comment: no I have added !important to the standard library classes of sapui5 so it is overriding

Comment: - Mechanic : "Uh, can you at least be specific about the problem or bring me the car?" - Santhosh : "No, I don't think there is a need for that, just give me the fix" :)

Comment: Think i have a parent container and it have 2 apps the first app which i have styled is overriding the view in the second application .Both the application are in the same container and I am overriding the standard library class using !important and that is the reason for this issue.

Comment: You just need a proper namespacing (i.e. top element css class) that prefix all your css declaration. Oh and you should never need important (since sapui5 doesnt use important, you should only rely on better selectors)

Comment: Except that is there any way we can overcome this issue

Comment: Learn how specifity works: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Simple things like `html .sapUiStrangeClass {}` can make your selector more specific than the original selector `.sapUiStrangeClass {}`. Since `!important` is causing problems, removing `!important` will be part of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the use of !important to the custom CSS properties.This practice should be avoided and CSS specificity should be used to overcome this issue.

- CSS specificity - [smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

credits to @Marc for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldnt override the standard classes.If you are You should give a custom class of your own to the control and cascade the styles.Like

```
    .YourCustomClass .sapMBtn{
background:red;
}
```